# About google map iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Anyone can tell me how to make a google map in my UIView like the iPhone original have. like Maps in iphone build in one

Answer (score 1):

1) Read the documentation for MKMapKit
2) Watch the WWDC videos for using MKMapKit.

Either of those will teach you more than a couple of lines here.

Comment: [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)